# cokernel of an onto linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I understand, by definition for $T:V\to W$ that is a linear transformation, $\text{coker}\,T=W/\text{im}\,T$. So, does this mean that the cokernel has an empty basis, and therefore $\dim \text{cokernel}\,T=0$? In other words, $\text{cokernel}\,T=\left\{0\right\}$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is onto that means $\operatorname{Im} T = W$, so $\operatorname{coker} T = W / \operatorname{Im} T = W/W \simeq \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily, if $T$ is on $W$ then yes. try to think of such linear transformations. for example, lets take,  $T:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $T(x)=(x,0)$, it is easy to see that $$dimIm(T)=1$$ then $$dimcoker (T)=1$$

got it?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to say that it is onto. I did to in the title however :). Thanks!